# Use 2 emails and credientials for send emails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a email and password at my `production` and `development` environments that is working fine.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'abc@gmail.com',
  :password => '******',
  :domain => 'gmail.com',
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain 
}
```

Now I want to use 2 different emails for send emails at `production` and `development` both.currently I'm using **'abc@gmail.com'** but I would like  to change this dynamically and Is this possible in rails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be able to just have a simple if in there and 2 versions of credentials ? like

```
if Rails.env.production?  
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
    :user_name => 'abc@gmail.com',  
    :password => '******',  
    :domain => 'gmail.com',  
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
    :port => 587,  
    :authentication => :plain  
  }  
else
  <other credentials>
end
```

If you wanted to dynamically change the credentials you would have to have a way to store and load the settings. I would create a model that maps to the smtp_settings so you can just call `ActionMailer::Base.smpt_settings = mail_settings` or however you want to call it. Then you would just have to call it before sending an email, and have an admin page that saves a different set of credentials.

Comment: my question was for changing the email and credential dynamically that I'm using for send the emails. Let suppose I want to send email by 'abc@xyz.com' and tomorrow I want to change this from my admin panel or from dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `from` address inside the mailer. You can change the code to send mail to something like given below.

```
mail(
  from: "<your dynamically set mail id here>"
  to: "<xyz@gmail.com>",
  subject: "Mail subject"
)
```

Also, I would suggest you to use SMTP services like **Sendgrid**/**AWS SNS**. Gmail tend to block sending mails after a number of mails.

Comment: if I will use from then what is the mean of emails configuration we are given at production and environment as mentioned in question. would I remove those from there ?

Comment: You are using gmail as the smtp provider here. You cannot remove that. You will be sending mails from the mentioned gmail account on behalf of the `from` mail address

Comment: okay then email that I'm  using here will not be use to send the email ?  or  from: "<your dynamically set mail id here>" this will use ?

Comment: User who receives the mail will only see "<your dynamically set mail id here>" - this mail id. But `abc@gmail.com` is actually sending the mail

Comment: okay  @Sebin but my question was for changing the email and credential dynamically that I'm using for send the emails instead  user who receives the mail will only see "<your dynamically set mail id here>".